# scp output as logfile

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am relatively new to using scp - and I am trying to do some simple stuff over ec2 - something like the following:

```
scp -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/path/to/file ~/path/to/dest/folder/file
```

What I would like to have is the log of the above command (i.e the screen output to a text file) - Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect both outputs (stdout, stderr) of the command with `&>` provided you use the verbose (`-v`) argument. Otherwise, `scp` will suppress the output as it expects its `stdout` to be connected to a terminal. But then you get too much information, which you can get rid of with `grep`:

```
scp -v -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/path/to/file ~/path/to/dest/folder/file |& grep -v ^debug > file.log
```

If you want to have the output both to the screen and the file, use `tee`

```
scp -v -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/path/to/file ~/path/to/dest/folder/file |& grep -v ^ debug tee file.log
```

Comment: I did try the first method earlier - but for scp, it does it work. You can try it yourself and see - it basically writes out an empty file.

Comment: Thank you very much for this (you saved me a lot of time!) - your first approach works perfectly for me. Voted your answer as the correct one. Just a small follow-up question: what if I wanted to append the `$date` to the above file.log? How does one handle this? Thanks again.

Comment: `{ date ; scp -v  -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/path/to/file ~/path/to/dest/folder/file ;  } |& grep -v ^debug > file.log `

Answer (score 0):

```
scp -v -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/p/t/file ~/p/t/d/f/file >> something.log 2>&1
```

`-v` and `2>&1` will append your extended details (i.e. debug info) in the existing `something.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Example if you want to combine scp folder transfer with `nohup`:

> touch /tmp/scp_nohup.log && nohup scp -v -r -o 'ProxyJump username1@ip1:port1' username2@ip2:/remote_path /local_path > /tmp/scp_nohup.log |& tail -F -s 0.5 /tmp/scp_nohup.log | grep -v debug

Answer (score -1):

How about (untested, compressing `/path/to` for readability):

```
(scp -i ec2key.pem username@ec2ip:/p/t/file ~/p/t/d/f/file ) 2>/p/t/textfile
```

Comment: This approach does not work for scp for some reason - and hence was my question `&>2` and `2>` simply does not work for scp's :( Not sure why.