# Run terminal command from within R: Show output from SCP transfer

Tags: r, command-line, scp

I'm calling a bash terminal command from within R. The command transfers a directory containing some files from a remote server using SCP.

When I run the command on the command line, I see a list of files that is transfered. I would like to also see or capture this output from within R.

```
command_to_run <- "scp -r root@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:~/path_to_dir/dir /Users/Me/.../target_path/"

system(command_to_run)
```

If I store the output in a variable and print that, it returns `character(0)`. I've also tried `system(command_to_run, intern = TRUE)`, but that doesn't help.

I think it might have to do with where the output of the `scp` command "is sent" on the command line. For example, if I just run `system("ls")` from within R, that works fine and returns the expected result, but outputs from `scp` are not shown within R.

Comment: Maybe output log file from scp, then read that file, see related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21205986/680068

Comment: There is also the `ssh` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh/ssh.pdf), which lets you handle `stdout` and `stderr` outputs consistently.